# Dividir resultado do sum e count na mesma Query?

Tags: laravel, count, laravel-5.5, sum

O código abaixo funciona, mas eu queria saber como fazer tudo isso direto na *query*, e se o jeito que eu estou montando ela é realmente a melhor forma.

```
$query = Avaliar::select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as contar'), DB::raw('SUM(nota) as total'))
        ->where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->first();

$nota = $query->total / $query->contar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia fazer a divisão na `SQL` da seguinte forma, exemplo:

```
$query = Avaliar::select(DB::raw('(SUM(nota) / COUNT(id)) as nota'))
        ->where('serie_id', $serie->id)
        ->first();

$nota = $query->nota;
```

agora, a sua e essa resposta chegam na mesma finalidade, então, tudo vai depender de onde vai ser utilizado, porque, dependendo da regra uma das duas sem encaixam.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)
- [Raw Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-methods)